# SQL: From JSON object select value when key is equal to search term

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, bigdata

In Google BigQuery I have a column in a table which contains JSON objects similar to this one

```
select JSON '[{"id":"A","value":"1"},{"id":"B","value":"2"},{"id":"C","value":"John"},{"id":"D","value":null},{"id":"E","value":"random"}]' as JSON_
```

I want to create a new column with the value of the JSON object where the id is equal to "B".
One way to solve this is as follows. But it only works if it is always the second object which has id = "B".

```
With table_ as (
select JSON '[{"id":"A","value":"1"},{"id":"B","value":"2"},{"id":"C","value":"John"},{"id":"D","value":null},{"id":"E","value":"random"}]' as JSON_
)

select JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_, '$[1].value') as value_2
from table_
```

Is there a more reliable method how to extract the json object value according to the specific id?

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider below if you're interested only in an *id* `B`.

```sql
SELECT (SELECT STRING(j.value) 
          FROM UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(JSON_)) j 
         WHERE STRING(j.id) = 'B'
       ) AS value_2
  FROM table_;
```

Answer (score 1):

bigquery is great for handle jsons and unstructured data, but sometimes its a pain to find the correct way

in your case, we need to:

1. Transform the json array to a array of jsons
2. Explode the array to each element have it own row
3. Get the json values of each json row

the query is the following

```
with

table_ as (
select
  json '[{"id":"A","value":"1"},{"id":"B","value":"2"},{"id":"C","value":"John"},{"id":"D","value":null},{"id":"E","value":"random"}]' as json_array_column
),

json_array_to_array_of_jsons as (
select
  json_extract_array(table_.json_array_column, '$.') as array_of_jsons
from
  table_
),

exploded_array_to_lines as (
select
  json_value(json_column, '$.id') as id,
  json_value(json_column, '$.value') as value
from
  json_array_to_array_of_jsons,
  unnest (array_of_jsons) as json_column
),

result as (
select
  *
from
  exploded_array_to_lines
where
  id = 'B'
)

select * from result
```

Comment: Hey @skulden, thanks for the help!  This answer is great and works well. I set Jaytigers answer as accepted answer simply because the output format is a bit easier to use for my usecase.